# PHP - How to call a an external name space within a class method?

Tags: php, oop

I'm using AWS's SDK that requires to use the following namespaces in my code:

```
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
```

I would like to call these namespaces in my class method to look as follows:

```
class EmailManager {
    public function sendEmail() {
        //new Aws\Ses\SesClient;

        use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
        use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
```

However, I get the following error when I call the namespaces `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use'`

This is what I tried so far and worked. However, I want to be able to call it in my method:

```
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

class EmailManager {
```

How can I call this namespaces in my class method?

Thank you

Comment: You can't place `use` statements inside the method. What is your reasoning behind wanting to place them inside the method?

Comment: What can I use instead of `use`? Do namespaces have to be called outside of the class?

Comment: put `use` outside the Class, and call by the Class name: `SesClient` not the full namespace.

Comment: You can omit the `use` statements altogether and do something similar to your commented line by invoking `new \Aws\Ses\SesClient` (note the leading backslash). Though I certainly don't see *why* you'd want to do it like that (then you'd have to write the fully qualified class name *every time* you use it). Import them through `use` once and then just call the class name as @AndréWalker pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

you should insert `use` outside the Class, and call the imported class by name: `SesClient` not the full namespace. Or don't put `use` at all and call by the full namespace every time.

see documentation:

[AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/ses-template.html)

[Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

with `use`:

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Ses\SesClient; 
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

class EmailManager {
    public function sendEmail() {
        $SesClient = new SesClient([
            'profile' => 'default',
            'version' => '2010-12-01',
            'region' => 'us-east-2'
        ]);
```

without `use`:

```php
class EmailManager {
    public function sendEmail() {
        $SesClient = new \Aws\Ses\SesClient([
            'profile' => 'default',
            'version' => '2010-12-01',
            'region' => 'us-east-2'
        ]);
```

Comment: One detail: without `use`, you need a leading backslash for the FQCN, so `new \Aws\Ses\SesClient`.